# how to run method in model instead of controller in laravel 5.1?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have following method in my controller:

```
public function store()
{
    $data=Input::all();
    User::create($data);
}
```

The above code works perfectly. My question is can we run the above method in model without writing in controller? And which is the best approach?

Answer (score 3):

you can try following way

in your model

```
public function insetUser()
{
        $input = Input::all();
        User::create($input);
    //here instead of User,you can use self like  self::create($input);
}
```

in controller you can

```
public function store()
{
    User::insetUser();
}
```

Comment: as said by @violator667. i also don't say its better or right way of doing . i just added possibility.lets see for future answers

Answer (score 2):

If it is in model, how you are going to trigger it?

It is in fact only one line of code

`User::create(Input::all());`

What it is here is the instance of model `User` and method `create` with injected model `Input`. Of couse you may set (model) `User.php`:

```
public function storedata()
{
 return $this->create(Input::all());
}
```

And then run it in your controller:

```
User::storedata();
```

But is it better? ;-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply .which is the best way ?

Comment: Apart of validation - I don't know how will it work when you use `User::storedata();` - I think the 'long' way is more clear - but this is only my opinion.

Comment: .thank you.i asked this question because usually model referred to database related and controller is like connecting model and view.so to clarify i asked this question

Answer (score 1):

In this circumstance, I don't think you gain much from moving things arounds.

If this is your Controller method:

```
public function store()
{
    $data=Input::all();
    User::create($data);
}
```

then this makes sense.  The input data is being handled by the controller method, and is being passed to the `create` method on your `User` Model.

If however, there was more logic required before creating a User record, then it'd be perfectly valid to abstract that logic to your `User` model.  But as it stands though, I think your current implementation is appropriate.